# Enable/disable an ordinary button on Form2 from Form1

Tags: forms, exception, button, controls

I need some help. I've been reading this site for days, and have read a lot of tips about controlling for example a button's property from another form. There's even a video on Youtube, which works to me as stand alone, but when I implenet it in my application it throws a NullReferenceException.

Let's say that I have a toolstrip menu on Form1. A click on the Kalibracio option opens the second form (also called Kalibracio - not Form2). Then, click on Proba in the menu should disable an ordinary button on the Kalibracio form which propery is set to public. The code on Form1 is as follows:

```
    private void kalibracioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Kalibracio Kalibr = new Kalibracio(this);
        Kalibr.Owner = this;
        Kalibr.Show();
    }

    private void probaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Kalibracio>().Any())
            (this.Owner as Kalibracio).button1.Enabled = false;
    // the above line throws a NullReferenceExcteption if Kalibracio form is open (Kalibracio is null)
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: To be exact, all i need is to change a property on a form Kalibracio that is opened _from_ Form1, and I want to make that change _from_ Form1 .... and I feel that I'm making a real mess of it

Answer (score 0):

LoL just had to declare globaly an instance of Kalibracio, open it and then access it's properties from all other methods.
I tried this approach at first, but my problem was that I was creating and instance locally, then I had to create another one in some other method because I couldn't address the former one created locally, and ofc it didn't work...